# How does using statement scope work when using Stream's created from other Stream's?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, using

I have a situation in which I am using multiple streams to download a zipped file via http. To do so I need to use multiple streams. I.e. get a web response stream, read into a binary reader stream, write to memory stream using binary writer stream etc etc.

As it's all a bit complicated and nasty I have split everything up into small functions to make it read a bit nicer, but I have a bit of a provlem with the `readStreamIntoMemoryStream` function which I am calling from the public `DownloadCsvReport` function, see below:

```
public IEnumerable<string> DownloadCsvReport(string reportDownloadUrl)
{
    using (Stream responseStream = creatDownloadWebRequest(reportDownloadUrl))
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = readStreamIntoMemoryStream(responseStream))
    {
        setMemoryStreamToBegining(memoryStream);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = getZippedFileFromMemoryStream(memoryStream);
        return convertZippedFileToCsvRows(zipEntry);
    }
}

private MemoryStream readStreamIntoMemoryStream(Stream webResponseStream)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
    var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(webResponseStream);

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(BufferSize);
        binaryWriter.Write(buffer);

        if (buffer.Length != BufferSize)
        {
            return memoryStream;
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I am unsure about is whether the `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` streams from the private function will be disposed of when the `MemoryStream` is when the public method loses scope? If not and I wrapped these stream's in using statements within the private method, would it not throw an exception when I tried to access the `MemoryStream` in the public method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing I am unsure about is whether the BinaryWriter and BinaryReader streams from the private function will be disposed of when the MemoryStream is when the public method loses scope?

The thing is, [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are **not** streams.

They act upon the underlying stream which, in your case, is the `memoryStream`.
So, as long as you close your `memoryStream` and the outer `responseStream`, everything is fine.

**Edit**:

In fact, take a look at their [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/BinaryWriter@cs/1305376/BinaryWriter@cs):

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
        OutStream.Close();
}
```

As you can see, all it does is call `Dispose` on the underlying stream. Your current code already does that - so there's no need to dispose of the writer/reader. It would be redundant.

Comment: Cool stuff, should have thought of checking that myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This was a design flaw in the .NET Framework that has been fixed as of .NET 4.5, where you can use overloads of the `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` constructors that allow you to leave the stream open after disposing them.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream, encoding, true))
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(webResponseStream, encoding, true))
{
    // ...
    return memoryStream;
}
```

**Edit**: If you're using .NET 4 (or earlier), you can use the `NonClosingStreamWrapper` class from Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) library:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var memoryStreamWrapper = new NonClosingStreamWrapper(memoryStream))
using (var webResponseStreamWrapper = new NonClosingStreamWrapper(webResponseStream))
using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStreamWrapper))
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(webResponseStreamWrapper))
{
    // ...
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: But surely this defies the point? I want them to be closed, just when I close the `MemoryStream` from the calling method! Is doing this not just the same as not disposing at all?

Comment: @dormisher: If you don't dispose the `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` within your `readStreamIntoMemoryStream` method, then they would remain open until processed by the garbage collector. By using the `IDisposable` pattern, you can ensure that they'd be disposed as soon as they're no longer needed.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the help. I am using .NET 4 so unfortunately I can't use these overloads, so I am forced to refactor my methods so I create all my streams in the public method.